# What is the best Classifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification

For instance if we are given a training set having more than 10000 data points(size of training set) and no of features more than 100000 and class labels near about 20 .So in this case which classifier(method like decision tree,svm,Naive bayes,neural network,boosting) would give me the most accuracy to classify the class labels of the test data .

Comment: You will need to **try them on your data**. There is no general rule.

Comment: The first step is to define *best*

Answer (score 5):

As noted in the comments, there is no general rule.

Since you have a fairly large number of training examples and a very high number of features, though, you'll probably want some kind of classifier that encourages feature sparsity. I'd try an SGD linear classifier with an L1 or elastic net penalty first.

See also [Andreas Mueller's flow chart of algorithms to try](http://peekaboo-vision.blogspot.com/2013/01/machine-learning-cheat-sheet-for-scikit.html):

[image]